# WordPress Main Menu Links Have Bullet Points And Aren't Horizontal

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Like the title says, I can't figure out why the links in my main menu on my local WordPress site are vertical with bullet points. Can someone please tell me how to get rid of the bullet points and make them load horizontal like they're supposed to?

Please check out the screenshot here: https://pasteboard.co/J7zvpjH.png

The CSS code for the menus:

```
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Menus
    --------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Small menu. */
    .menu-toggle,
    .main-navigation.toggled ul {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {

        .menu-toggle {
            display: none;
        }

        .main-navigation ul {
            display: flex;
        }
    }

    .site-main .comment-navigation,
    .site-main
    .posts-navigation,
    .site-main
    .post-navigation {
        margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    }

    .comment-navigation .nav-links,
    .posts-navigation .nav-links,
    .post-navigation .nav-links {
        display: flex;
    }

    .comment-navigation .nav-previous,
    .posts-navigation .nav-previous,
    .post-navigation .nav-previous {
        flex: 1 0 50%;
    }

    .comment-navigation .nav-next,
    .posts-navigation .nav-next,
    .post-navigation .nav-next {
        text-align: end;
        flex: 1 0 50%;
    }
```

```
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

                <!-- NAVBAR -->
                <div class="navbar-wrapper">

                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap To WordPress"></a>
                            </div><!-- navbar-header -->
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul><!-- nav -->
                            </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
                        </div><!-- container -->

                    </div><!-- navbar -->

                </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->

            </header>
```

```
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

                <!-- NAVBAR -->
                <div class="navbar-wrapper">

                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>

                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap To WordPress"></a>
                            </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                            <!-- If the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "container". In other words, it overwrites the "container_class". Ref: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-menu_class-usage-bug/?replies=4 -->

                            <?php // Added this PHP script to my Bootstrap to Wordpress theme's code
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(

                                        'theme_location'   => 'primary',
                                        'container'        => 'nav',
                                        'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                                        'menu_class'       => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                                    ) );
                                ?>

                        </div><!-- container -->

                    </div><!-- navbar -->

                </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->

            </header>
```

```
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

                <!-- NAVBAR -->
                <div class="navbar-wrapper">

                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>

                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap To WordPress"></a>
                            </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                            <!-- If the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "container". In other words, it overwrites the "container_class". Ref: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-menu_class-usage-bug/?replies=4 -->

                            <?php // Added this PHP script to my Bootstrap to Wordpress theme's code
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(

                                        'theme_location'   => 'primary',
                                        'container'        => 'nav',
                                        'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse main-navigation',
                                        'menu_class'       => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                                    ) );
                                ?>

                        </div><!-- container -->

                    </div><!-- navbar -->

                </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->

            </header>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML snippet of the menu so we can help identify the correct selector

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the bullet points by setting the "list-style-type" of your "ul" element to "none". Try setting the "flex-direction" to "row" (it is the default value), to make sure it was not overwritten somewhere. You can use the "flex" property to set the flexible length of flexible elements.

```
.main-navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.main-navigation li {
    flex: auto;
}
```

If this is not working for you, do you mind sharing your html markup of the list?
There could be a problem accessing the right elements in the css, so the code is not getting applied to your elements. Or there are some classes or dependencies that are influencing the behaviour of your list elements.

**EDIT:** I just checked your new added html code, thank you. You are not giving the class of "main-navigation" to the parent of your ul. So your css styles are not applied. So you need to add the class to the navbar-collapse div container.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse main-navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul><!-- nav -->
</div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
```

When using the wp_nav_menu function, you can put the class to "container_class".

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(

    'theme_location'   => 'primary',
    'container'        => 'nav',
    'container_class'  => 'navbar-collapse collapse main-navigation',
    'menu_class'       => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

) );
?>
```

You can access your header.php in Wordpress via FTP, or alternatively with using the backend, you can go to Design -> Theme-Editor -> and select the header.php file on the right side. Edit the code and save the file.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply, but that didn't change anything. I added the HTML for the header as you requested.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code! I just updated my answer. Your are not giving the class to the element in your html markup.

Comment: Thanks, rank. Can you please tell me where or how I would add main-navigation to my header.php so that it works on the dynamic WordPress site? I added the code that is inside the header tags on my header.php

Comment: Just edited my answer and added the way you add the class to the wp_nav_menu function. At the end of my answer I descriped how you can edit your header.php file in Wordpress. When you are happy with the answer and the problem is solved, I would be happy if you mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I added main-navigation to container_class and saved the file and refreshed the page, but it didn't change anything. Anything else you think it could be?

Comment: By it didn't change, do you mean there is no effect, but the class is added when you inspect your site in browser? Did you paste my css changes to the style.css of your theme?

Comment: Yes. There is no effect. The problem is still there just like it was before I added your CSS and HTML and header.php code. I also deleted my browser history and refreshed the page. I made a Loom video to show you.

Please see my Loom video: 

https://www.loom.com/share/7602d873349a4ed89c6b7502c85f4a56

Comment: Thanks, what is that index.html doing there? it is not part of a normal theme struture, because there is an index.php? Just to be 100% sure, you check in the browser inspector if both the code in the header and in the css is displayed and applied, but still flex not working? If you haven't checked, please do. Their might be something from with your template structur rather than the css property of flex. If all code is in place, the browser inspector should show you if it is overwritten by something or not getting correctly called by the class.

Comment: The index.html is the static version of the website. Yikes. I wouldn't even know what do to after right-clicking and choosing "Inspect" in Google Chrome. Sorry, but I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to web development and especially when it comes to using Chrome dev tools. How would I do this:

"Just to be 100% sure, you check in the browser inspector if both the code in the header and in the css is displayed and applied, but still flex not working?"

I know how to open up the <head> section in Chrome dev tools, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You are looking for the code in your <body> so this is where you have to look in. You have the code, so look for:     <header class="site-header" role="banner">  and check down there, if the div with the class "main-navigation" exists. If it does, click on it. you will see right to the html inspector now the css information applied to the clicked class. Is there the list-style-type set to none and the display flex information? -  The google chrome inspector always shows on default html and css side by side. If you click the elements in the html side, the css on the right side will show up.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said to do and after opening all the toggle arrows in Chrome Inspector, I found the header class="site-header" role="banner" and I opened up all the toggle arrows in that section and even did a control+F search for the word "main" and "main-navigation" is nowhere to be found in my code anywhere.

Please see the screenshots here: 

https://pasteboard.co/J7SwAz4.png
 and here: https://pasteboard.co/J7SyYBP.png
 and here https://pasteboard.co/J7SzhJu.png

Comment: So this is the proof that you changes to your header.php are not saved. The page is not getting the file, where the markup has been changed and has the added "main-navigation" class. How are you editing it? Please delete this index.html or put it in subfolder, it may cause problems. It also could be, that you style.css is also not updated, but you can find that out, if you got the header.php to save and apply your changes.

Comment: Okay. So, weirdest thing happened. I am building this website I've been having trouble with as I follow along in an online course, and the instructor had us create a new Footer Menu option in functions.php so that we can choose a Footer menu in Appearance/Menus and after I did that and went back to Appearance/Menus and added my new footer menu and refreshed the page, my Main Menu at the top got fixed somehow! I don't know why that happened!

Comment: That's great you got it working! I guess the question was how to get rid of the bullet points and to align the menu items vertically. The answer I offered included the css code to achieve that. Your styles not getting applied first was caused by your functions.php. But I think someone with the wish to get rid of the bullet points and to align the items will find help with my answer. If you are happy, you can accept the answer.